# Jade. Don´t close a tag on a interation

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, tags, pug

I am trying to make a logs register of a program I made, and I am trying to do over html (using node and jade... just like the program). And I want separate the logs lines by month with a collapsable element (using bootstrap).

Pseudo-code:
The first iteration over the content of the database of the logs must to open the collapsabe and insert the log line, and after, on the elements where the day (it is a column of the database) is first day of month, it must to close all the old collapsable tags, and open a new one (and insert the log line). On the rest of the case it only must to insert the log line.

Code (jade):

```
mixin accordion(info)
    div.panel.panel-default
        div.panel-heading
            h4.panel-title
                a(data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#day#{info.day}#{info.month}#{info.year}") Mes #{info.month} de #{info.year}
        div(id="day#{info.day}#{info.month}#{info.year}" class="panel-collapse collapse in")
            div.panel-body 
                !{info.text}
-index = 0
div#acordion.panel-group
    for info in serial
        -if(index==0)
            -index=2
            mixin accordion(info)
         -else if(info.day==1 && index==1)
            -index=2;
            mixin accordion(info)
         -else if(info.day > 1)
            -index=1;
            |!{info.text}
         -else
            |!{info.text}
```

On the first iteration works fine, it open and insert the first line of the log on a accordion, but the problem that I find is that at every iteration after first, it doesn´t insert the new lines on the correct place, the collapsable´s div.panel.panel-default tag close... and nevermore returns to open (until a new day 1 of month... where it returns to do the same: first line good, and the others wrong).

A picture is worth a thousand words.
[image: wrong closing of the tags]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
mixin accordion(info, text)
div.panel.panel-default
    div.panel-heading
            h4.panel-title
                a(data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#day#{info.day}#{info.month}#{info.year}") Mes #{info.month} de #{info.year}
        div(id="day#{info.day}#{info.month}#{info.year}" class="panel-collapse collapse in")
            div.panel-body 
                !{text}
                -text = ''

-index = 0
-text = ''
for info in serial
    -if(info.day==1 && index==1)
        -index=2;
        mixin accordion(info, text)
    -else if(info.day > 1)
        -index=1;
        -text += info.text
    -else
        -text += info.text

-if(text != '')
    mixin accordion({day:'actual', month:'actual', year:'actual'}, text)
```

It seems that works!!!